# Amplify GraphQL get item from other field than ID

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I am implementing a webpage with React and AWS Amplify.

I have the following definition in my `schema.graphql` file:

```
type Calendar @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  description: String
  url: String!
  intervals: [Interval] @connection(keyName: "byCalendar", fields: ["id"])
}
```

I would like to get a calendar from its URL string. Unfortunately, the following code throws an error:

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getCalendar, { url: "some-url"}));
```

`Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided.`

From the error, providing the id is mandatory. However, I would like to be able to get an object from just the url.

How can I do that?

I am using the queries automatically generated by the amplify's cli.

```
/* eslint-disable */
// this is an auto generated file. This will be overwritten

export const getCalendar = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetCalendar($id: ID!) {
    getCalendar(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      description
      url
      intervals {
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listCalendars = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListCalendars(
    $filter: ModelCalendarFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listCalendars(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        description
        url
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to add a "byURL" key to the model like so:

```
type Calendar @model @key(name: "byURL", fields: ["url", "id"], queryField: "calendarByURL") {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    url: String
    intervals: [Interval] @connection(keyName: "byCalendar", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Then write a custom query using that new key (or have amplify to regenerate the queries based on the updated schema.graphql file):

```
export const getCalendarByURL = /* GraphQL */ `
    query calendarByURL($url: String!) {
        calendarByURL(url: $url) {
            items {
                id
                name
                description
                url
                intervals {
                    nextToken
                }
                createdAt
                updatedAt
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

And this would let me do:

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(customQueries.getCalendarByURL, { url: "some-url"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions you now have to replace the @key directive in the following way (see GraphQL [Transformer v2](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/)):

```
type Calendar @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    url: String @index(name: "byUrl", queryField: "calendarByUrl")
    intervals: [Interval] @connection(keyName: "byCalendar", fields: ["id"])
}
```